# Best approach for SP2016 on prem configuration for HA

Tags: sharepoint-server, installation, configuration

We are a team of 100-150 users and I have to configure a SP2016 on prem farm with HA.

Basically our farm is going to have 2 site collections with few large lists.

I have been given 2 SP servers and 2 SQL servers.

How do I utilize the 2 SP servers for HA?

Can i configure 1 WFE and 1 App server or configure both servers to be WFE with search and service application running on 1 server?

Please advise

Answer (score 5):

With only two SharePoint servers, they should run all of the same roles while your SQL Server uses an AlwaysOn Availability Group.

Comment: Make sure the web servers are physically separated and your load balancer is fault tolerant as well.  Also, make sure to use SQL aliases when you are setting up SP.

Comment: No, do NOT use a SQL alias with Always On. The point of SQL Aliases is mobility -- Always On provides that. Always use the AOAG Listener endpoint (this will be an FQDN).

For SharePoint servers, residing in the same datacenter is the ideal placement. Stretched farms are not recommended. DR/BCP is a different conversation that requires a secondary farm at a remote location.

Comment: @TrevorSeward Do you mean both SP servers should run all the services? Means both SP servers should act as WFE and App servers right?

Comment: That's correct, for high availability if you only have two nodes. I usually recommend four nodes... but for 100-150 users, performance should be a non-issue given you can appropriate size up the VMs as the need arises. I would recommend paying close attention to vCPU/vRAM -- you may need upwards of 6-8 vCPU/18-24GB vRAM for your SharePoint servers since you would be running everything on just two servers. This is primary for Distributed Cache, Search, and of course user interaction with sites and files.

Comment: @TrevorSeward, Yes both SP servers have 32 GB RAM and 8 core processor